# hand over function to onClick on props with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encapsulated some HTML code to a extra class and want to hand over a function to it now.

The parent class looks like this:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  doSomething = id => {
  console.log(id);
  // here are some fetch operations only available in Home component
  };

  render() {
  return (
  <Child doSomething={() => this.doSomething} />
  )
  }
}
```

my Child component then looks like this:

```
const id = 3;
const Child = ({doSomething}) =>
(

   <Button onClick={doSomething(id)}>Click</Button>
);
export default Child
```

I was trying around with different solutions but either I get no result or the onClick function is called when the Home component is rendered instead of when clicking on the button.
I want the function to be executed when the button is clicked. And the id parameter should be handed over as well. I can't have the function in the Child component itself since I have to use some redux actions in it which are not available in the child class.

I know this is not a too difficult question but I'm still a noob with JavaScript..

Edit: I accomplished having the event parameter inside my function but I wonder how to access the id with it. I can't simply add a prop to the Button element since it does not allow that.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind method in constructor and pass it to child component

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
  }

  doSomething(id) {
    console.log(id);
    // here are some fetch operations only available in Home component
  }

  render() {
    return <Child doSomething={this.doSomething} />
  }
}
```

And in `Child`

```
const Child = ({doSomething}) =>
(

   <Button onClick={() => doSomething(id)}>Click</Button>
)
```

Comment: This worked as supposed with my code thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
this.doSomething.bind(this);
```

It binds `this` as the first argument of your function, which is needed when you pass a class method as a reference. When `doSomething` is called in the child component, `this` will reference the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in `Home` component use arrow function as `doSomething` prop to preserve correct context (alternatively you can use `bind` in component constructor):

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  doSomething(id) {
     console.log(id);
     // here are some fetch operations only available in Home component
  }

  render() {
      <Child doSomething={() => this.doSomething()} />
  }
}
```

and then use arrow function that will call passed function with given value as click handler in child component:

```
<Button onClick={() => doSomething(id)}>Click</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your jsx is wrong. Your are missing

```
render() {
  return ...;
}
```

There is no valid JSX `Button`

`<Button onClick={doSomething(id)}>Click</Button>`,
use `<button>` tag instead.

Here is working example.

```js
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;

class Home extends React.Component {

  doSomething = id => {
  console.log(id);
  // here are some fetch operations only available in Home component
  };

  render() {
    return <Child doSomething={() => this.doSomething('do something input')} />;
  
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    //console.log(props);
  }

  
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.doSomething.bind(this)}>Click</button>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>




<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you I forgot to add it in my minimal example, I added the return statement to avoid confusion for others

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass the id when you are defining the fat arrow function

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  doSomething(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }

  render() {
    return <Child doSomething={(id) => this.doSomething(id)} />
  }
}
```